# Vite build .js file in rolling update deployment strategy

Tags: vue.js, deployment, amazon-ecs, vite, rolling-updates

I have an issue and I'm not sure how to approach it, maybe someone can help
I'm using ECS rolling deployment, which means it is setting up the container, and once it's healthy and ready to use it dropping the previous revision
and I have a load balancer in front of it
now when I deploy a new revision I sometimes get this error in my browser
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html"

the reason is that the load balancer probably points to a different container while rolling the update
so when I hit the domain it tries to load the asset /assets/chunk-[hash].js and when it tries to hit that chunk-hash.js it probably goes to the new revision where this file does not exist because on every build the hash generated is unique

I haven't found any solution whatsoever online
but I think the solution for this is to use the same chunk name.
or do you have any other recommendations?

Thanks!

Comment: Same chunk name will cause the browser to cache the old version, which is just going to cause other issues. In this type of scenario you might be better off doing blue-green deployments, or maybe enable sticky-sessions on the load balancer to prevent requests from one browser going to different versions of your app (although in general I hate to recommend sticky-sessions).

Comment: Sticky session sounds like a great solution, what are the downsides , I’m curious why you don’t recommend it

Comment: The downside of sticky sessions is that your traffic won't be as evenly distributed across multiple backend servers as it could be.

Comment: Awesome! works like magic!
I set the sticky session just for 5 minutes, it takes about 1-2 minutes to replace the old container